# Delete URL after rename [SP online]

Tags: sharepoint-online, url

On my project I've come to realize I have to rename some site collections.
example:  mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/collectionName      *to*     mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/OtherName

So in the admin center I renamed my url from collectionName to OtherName. however  /sites/collectionName is still forwarding traffic to /OtherName.

What can I do to make the /sites/collectionName  url available for a new site collection ?

Comment: You should wait for a few hours for the url to be available.

Comment: thanks, i'll give this a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The redirect is by design as noted in the docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-site-address - It will stay this way to make sure that all old links to the site still will work after the address have been changed.

However, you can manually free up these URLs by following the instructions here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-redirects

```
Remove-SPOSite -Identity https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/OldSiteName
```

Comment: ok thanks, so a1mery is incorrect ?

Comment: Yes. The urls will not be freed up automatically. Source: first paragraph of the second link in my answer...

Comment: My bad, thanks Rune for correcting me :)

Comment: So you simply can't do it online? You have to have PowerShell? That's seriously messed up.